# MYSQL Lost connection to MySQL server during query after many queries

Tags: python, mysql, flask

After I a certain number of SQL requests (~150) my app fails. I am using the `mysql.connector` library. How do I fix?

Comment: You've likely exhausted the number of concurrent connections your server is configured for. It's worth checking that you're properly recycling your connections.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.